# HTML/CSS - Assigning absolute position based on center of page

Tags: html, css

I've added some really cool decoration to my website. I assign their positions using left and right attributes in my CSS, like so:

```
left: 32px;
position: absolute;
```

Now, if a user has a really wide screen, the positioning of these decorations will be a bit off. So I was wondering, instead of assigning these images based of the left or right end of the screen, is it possible to assign their position from center, like:

```
rightOfCenter: 12px;
```

Searched but found nothing. This feature may not exist, but it would be really cool if it did! Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more context to your question? If you could create a jsfiddle example too it'll be much easier to understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a left margin to 50%, for example, and then use the left property to position the element further.

```
div {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:50%;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/G69RK/

Try messing around with the `left` property. So your `rightOfCenter: 12px;` is actually `left: 12px` now.

Answer (score 1):

You may include a blank div in the middle of the screen and align the rear widgets with padding in base of the center div.

[image: the line in the center is the blank div]

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
display:flex;
width:500px;
height:500px;
}
.child{
margin:auto;
width:10px;
height:10px;
```

}

This will position the child element always in the center of the parent element.
If you want to align it 13px right of the center just do margin: auto calc(50% - 13px) auto auto; 
http://jsbin.com/somiw/1/edit